# Need help for a proof for convergence of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need help for the following proof.

As I felt that something is not very right at my attempt but I cannot tell what's wrong.

The Question is as follows:

Suppose the sequence $\{{b_n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a real number sequence.

For real numbers $L$ and $c$, the interval $(L - c, L + c)$ contains infinitely many terms of the above sequence, no matter how small the interval is .

Prove that the above sequence converges to $L$.

My attempt:

By the definition of convergence of a sequence,

i.e. $x$ is the limit of a sequence ${x_n}$ if for each real number $c > 0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that,

for every natural number $n$ larger than or equal to $N$, $|x_n - x| < c$.

$|x_n - x| < c$ implies that $x - c < x_n < x + c$,

which implies that $x_n$ lies within the interval $(x - c, x + c)$ for all $n$ larger than or equal to a natural number $N$, where x is the limit of the sequence.

For my question, we replace $x$ by $L$, i.e. the interval $(L - c, L + c)$.

Below are my queries:

As the question mentioned that infinitely many terms of the sequence ${b_n}$ are within the interval $(L - c, L + c)$, it seems that the $m$-tail of the sequence (i.e. the terms $b_m$, $b_m+1$, $b_m+2$,...) are all contained in the interval $(L - c, L + c)$, which will then showed that the sequence converges to $L$.

However, I am not sure if the "infinitely many terms of the sequence" really implies that the whole $m$-Tail are within the interval $(L - c, L + c)$, and I need some clarification here.

Also, if NOT the whole $m$-Tail are within the interval $(L - c, L + c)$, then there may be some other finite or infinitely many terms of the sequence ${b_n}$ that DON'T lie within the interval $(L - c, L + c)$.

Which may results in the sequence not converging to $L$, and the sequence may either be converging to another number $K$ or divergent, is that also correct?

If NOT the whole $m$-Tail is within the interval, can I still prove that the sequence ${b_n}$ converges to $L$?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can't prove that claim since it is wrong. A sequence having two convergent sequences to different limits satisfies the claim for L = one of the limits.

Comment: Please use MathJax when formatting your question: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @user26857, so i need to create a sequence with 2 sub sequences that converges to 2 different limits as a counter example to disprove the claim? Can I create a sequence with 2 sub sequences that one of the sub sequences converge to the limit L this question suggest, and another sub sequence being divergent, i.e. a cosine function? Will that also disprove the claim of the question?